How to prove SVD theorem?
I am reading a proof of the SVD theorem. But there are two parts of it that I don't understand. Here is part of the book:

Proof. The matrix $A^{\mathrm{T}} A$ is symmetric and by Lemma 7.4, its eigenvalues are real and nonnegative. Listing the eigenvalues in descending order we obtain
$$
\sigma_1^2 \geq \sigma_2^2 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_r^2 \geq \sigma_{r+1}^2 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n^2 \geq 0
$$
Assume that the first $r$ eigenvalues are positive, and the eigenvalues $\sigma_{r+1}^2=\sigma_{r+2}^2=\cdots \sigma_n^2=0$. Let
$$
\widetilde{\Sigma}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\Sigma & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right],
$$
where $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_r\right)$ is a diagonal matrix of singular values. The spectral theorem (Theorem 7.6) guarantees that $A^{\mathrm{T}} A$ has an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ of eigenvectors. Let
$$
V=\left[\begin{array}{lllll}
v_1 & v_2 & \ldots & v_{n-1} & v_n
\end{array}\right],
$$
and it turns out this is the matrix we are looking for. We now need to find $U$. The matrix $U$ must be orthogonal, so its columns will form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let
$$
u_i=\frac{A v_i}{\sigma_i}, \quad 1 \leq i \leq r .
$$
These vectors are orthonormal since
$$
\left\langle u_i, u_j\right\rangle=\frac{\left(A v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(A v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=\frac{\left(\sigma_i v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(\sigma_j v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=v_i^{\mathrm{T}} v_j=\left\langle v_i, v_j\right\rangle=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & i \neq j \\
1 & i=j
\end{array} .\right.\tag{1}
$$
If $r<m$, we still need $m-r$ additional vectors $\left\{\begin{array}{llllll}u_{r+1} & u_{r+1} & \ldots & u_{m-1} & u_m\end{array}\right\}$ so that $\left\{\begin{array}{llllll}u_1 & u_2 & \ldots & u_{m-1} & u_m\end{array}\right\}$ forms an orthonormal set. Beginning with
$$
u_1, u_2, \ldots u_{r-1}, u_r
$$
use a Gram-Schmidt algorithm step to add the standard basis vector $e_{r+1}$ to the set to obtain the orthonormal set
$$
u_1, u_2, \ldots u_{r-1}, u_r, u_{r+1}
$$
Continue by adding in the same fashion $e_{r+2}, e_{r+3}, \ldots, e_m$ to obtain the basis
$$
u_1, u_2, \ldots u_{m-1}, u_m
$$

First, I don't know why $\frac{\left(A v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(A v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=\frac{\left(\sigma_i v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left( \sigma_j v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}$, or I don't know why $Av_i=\sigma_i v_i$. I tried to multiply both sides of $A^{\mathrm{T}}Av_i=\sigma^2v_i$ by $A$, but I can only get $Av_i$ to be the eigenvector of $AA^{\mathrm{T}}$.
Second, I don't know why $e_{r+1}$ is linearly independent of $u_1,\cdots,u_r$. $e_{r+1}$ denotes the vector where the $r+1$th position is $1$ and the other positions are $0$. I'm clueless about this.
Can you give me some tips, thank you very much!

The equality
$$
\frac{\left(A v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(A v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=\frac{\left(\sigma_i v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left( \sigma_j v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}
$$
is right, but it doesn't follow trivially. What happens is that
$$
\frac{\left(A v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(A v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=\frac{v_i A^{\mathrm{T}}Av_j}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}
=\frac{\sigma_j^2\,v_i^{\mathrm T}v_j}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}
=\frac{\sigma_j}{\sigma_i}\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}.
$$
As for your second question, you are right that the canonical basis vector $e_{r+1}$ need not be orthogonal to $u_1,\ldots,u_r$. But if $r<m$ there is some unit vector orthogonal to them, and you can add it to the list.

Was wondering the same thing. Why should $\frac{\sigma_j}{\sigma_i}$ be one? Not that it matters much, since you can normalize the vectors easily, but I think as given the vectors are only pairwise orthogonal.

When $i\ne j$ , you are multiplying $\frac{\sigma_j}{\sigma_i}$ by zero, so its value is irrelevant.

Sure, but the proof claims that the $u_i$ form a orthonormal basis.

Yes. They do, since the $v_i$ were chosen orthonormal as per the  question.

Nevermind, if $i=j$ this is of course one.

And then again the whole equation $\frac{\left(A v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left(A v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}=\frac{\left(\sigma_i v_i\right)^{\mathrm{T}}\left( \sigma_j v_j\right)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}$ is trivially true but a bit misleading in a proof, since it's actually not what's following. Sorry for going on a tangent here.
